# breadcrumbs from split into single string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string separated by `"/"` which I need to make into breadcrumbs.

I have tried this, but the `x` is not working.

```
var path = "sub1/sub2/sub3";
var breadcrumbs = path.split('/');
for(var i = 0, l = breadcrumbs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var x = path.substring(0, breadcrumbs[i].length);
    
    console.log( x );
}
```

`x` needs to be the full path from the beginning, right to the last one selected.

for example, if you were to click on `"sub2"` in the breadcrumbs, the value should be `sub1/sub2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use [`Array#join()`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) `breadcrumbs.slice(0, i + 1).join('/')`:

```js
var path = "sub1/sub2/sub3";
var breadcrumbs = path.split('/');
for (var i = 0, l = breadcrumbs.length; i < l; i++) {
  var x = breadcrumbs.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');

  console.log(x);
}
```